# electron change position of dev menu

Tags: electron

Is it possible to make my devTools dock to bottom by default?
I am completely new at electron, and this project took me 8 minutes to set up so excuse my design.
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfveL.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**contents.openDevTools([options])**

- `options` Object (optional)

  - `mode` String - Opens the devtools with specified dock state, can be right, bottom, undocked, detach. Defaults to last used dock state. In undocked mode it's possible to dock back. In detach mode it's not.

So in your code in the Main process, it should be something like this

```
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'bottom' })
```

[webContents API](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md)

Answer (score 0):

**This can be eaisly done as follows**

```
window.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: "bottom"});
```

**or as follows**

```
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `{ mode: 'undocked' }` , then you can see the different options to put you devtool when it's launched, but maybe you can't use some mode, like bottom or right. good luck!